# Remove multiple views from superview

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, sdk

I need remove several `UIViews` form `superview` simultaneously when use this method :

```
[view1 , view 2 , vie3 removeFromSuperview];
```

compiler gives me a warning :

> ```
> **warning: Unused Entity Issue: Expression result unused**
> ```

How can do it right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Swift**

```
view.subviews.forEach { $0.removeFromSuperview() }
```

**Objective C**

```
[view.subviews makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];
```

Answer (score 5):

Or, if you want to remove all subviews from a certain view:

```
for (UIView *subview in view.subviews) {
    [subview removeFromSuperview];
}
```